# how does jsp:useBean scope attribute work?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, jsp-tags, usebean

I am trying to understand how exactly `scope` attribute in `jsp:useBean` JSP action tag works. In my understanding `scope` is used to indicate where the bean is located (request,session,application etc.), but after some testing I came across an interesting situation where it's not the case, please consider the following JSP code (I am using scriplets here just for the sake of simplicity):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  import="package2JSP.User" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%
        User user1 = new User("id1","name1");
        User user2 = new User("id2","name2");
        request.setAttribute("user", user1);
        session.setAttribute("user", user2);
    %>
    <%-- Here I expect to create user bean that represents user2 from session scope--%>
    <jsp:useBean id="user" class="package2JSP.User" scope="session"/>

    <%-- Here I expect user name to be name2 but it is name1 instead--%>
    <jsp:getProperty property="name" name="user"/>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically here I created 2 users objects and set them as "user" attributes in request and session scopes, when I tried to retrieve "user" from "session" scope using `jsp:useBean` it seems as if "user" from "request" scope was retrieved.

Can you please explain me why it happened? And what was the development reason to make `jsp:useBean` work this way instead of normally selecting the attribute from the specified scope, are there any advantages of it?

Now I know I could use JSTL/EL to retrieve the needed value i.e. `<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.name}" />` but I just want to know how `jsp:useBean` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation are 2 tags involved:

- jsp:useBean
- jsp:getProperty

**The jsp:useBean**

According to [Specification - CHAPTER JSP.5 - JSP.5.1 `<jsp:useBean>`](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf):

> A jsp:useBean  action associates **an instance**  of a Java programming
>   language  object **defined within a given  scope**  and **available with a
>   given  id  with a newly  declared scripting variable of the same  id** .
>   When a    action is used in an scriptless page, or in an
>   scriptless  context (as in the body of an action so indicated), there
>   are no Java scripting  variables created but instead an EL variable is
>   created.

The compiled java code is:

```
      package2JSP.User user = null;
      synchronized (session) {
        user = (package2JSP.User) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("user", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
        if (user == null){
          try {
            user = (package2JSP.User) java.beans.Beans.instantiate(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), "package2JSP.User");
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
            throw new InstantiationException(exc.getMessage());
          } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot create bean of class " + "package2JSP.User", exc);
          }
          _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("user", user, PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
        }
      }
```

If you want to access this user object you can use a scriptlet(expression) `<%=user.getName()%>`

**The jsp:getProperty**

According to [Specification - CHAPTER JSP.5 - JSP.5.3 `<jsp:getProperty>`](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf)say:

> The value of the name attribute in 
>   jsp:setProperty  and  jsp:getProperty  will  refer to an object that 
>   is obtained from the  pageContext  object through its  findAttribute
>   method.

The JSP Compiler make from the `jsp:getProperty` tag a call to the [`findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29):

```
out.write(org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.toString(
  (((package2JSP.User)_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("user")).getName())));
```

> `findAttribute()`
>   Searches for the named attribute in page, request, session (if valid),
>   and application scope(s) in order and returns the value associated or
>   null.

Basically: the first match is returned.

Using `useBean` and `getProperty` is considered bad practice.
Using JSTL/EL is the better way to work with attributes.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This seems to me more like a design/development flaw, if `jsp:getProperty` uses `findAttribute` to get its value then logically I could get rid of `<jsp:useBean id="user" class="package2JSP.User" scope="session"/>` line in my jsp file and I should still get "name1" for `<jsp:getProperty property="name" name="user"/>` because `user` is still in the request and session scopes.

Comment: When I tried to do this I got an exception which probably means when you use `getProperty` the bean must be defined through `jsp:useBean`. Well any way I tried to get the correct value using `<%=user.getName()%>` as you suggested and it worked so the culprit here is definitely `jsp:getProperty` not `jsp:useBean`.